# openjpa, update, error 'PK has non-default value'

Tags: java, jpa, db2, websphere, openjpa

I wonder if anyone has come across this error and can explain what's happening:

```
<openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1087028 nonfatal user error>
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: 
Primary key field com.qbe.config.bean.QBEPropertyHistory.id of com.qbe.config.bean.QBEPropertyHistory@1c710ab has non-default value. 
The instance life cycle is in PNewProvisionalState state and hence an 
existing non-default value for the identity field is not permitted. 
You either need to remove the @GeneratedValue annotation or modify the 
code to remove the initializer processing.
```

I have two objects, Property and PropertyHistory. Property has OneToMany List of PropertyHistory:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval=false)
@JoinColumn(name="PROPERTY_NAME")
@OrderBy("updatedTime DESC")
private List<QBEPropertyHistory> history = new ArrayList<QBEPropertyHistory>();
```

And Property object is loaded and saved like this:

```
public T find(Object id) {
    T t = null;
    synchronized(this) {
        EntityManager em = getEm();
        t = em.find(type, id);
        //em.close(); //If this is uncommented, fetch=LAZY doesn't work. And fetch=EAGER is too slow.
    }
    return t;
}

public T update(T t) {
    synchronized(this) {
        EntityManager em = getEm();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        t = em.merge(t);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return t;
    }
}
```

In the service layer I load a property using find(id) method, instantiate a new PropertyHistory, add it into property prop.getHistory().add(propHist) then call update(prop) and get the above error.

The error disappears if I close EntityManager in find() but that breaks lazy loading and prop.getHistory() always returns null. If I set fetch=EAGER it becomes unacceptably slow as there are 10s of 1000s of records and I need to select thousands of property objects at a time and history is not needed 99.99% of the time.

I can't remove the @GeneratedValue as the error text suggests because it is generated (DB2, autoincrement). Now I wonder how would i "modify the code to remove the initializer processing" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to share an Entity across persistence contexts(`EntityManager`). You could change your methods to take an `EntityManager` instance and use the same EM for the find and update operations.

Comment: Hmm... apparently that only worked while there was one user, as soon as there's two, this error is thrown: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1179900 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Multiple concurrent threads attempted to access a single broker. By default brokers are not thread safe; if you require and/or intend a broker to be accessed by more than one thread, set the openjpa.Multithreaded property to true to override the default behavior